# Update nos valores da coluna CD_SETOR em todas as tabelas encontradas com a coluna

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, sql-update, tabela-banco-de-dados

Usando o select `SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE column_name like 'CD_SETOR'` eu tenho como resultado muitas tabelas com owner diferente com o mesmo CD_SETOR. EX:

```
    Owner    Tables                          Column     Type         
210 MVINTEGRA   INTEGRA_ENTRADA_SOLICIT_AGDM CD_SETOR   NUMBER
211 MVINTEGRA   INTEGRA_ENTRADA_SOL_AGDM     CD_SETOR   NUMBER
212 DBAMV   V_FFCV_ESTEIRA_CONTAS            CD_SETOR   NUMBER
213 DBAPS   ITCONTAH_REJEITADA               CD_SETOR   NUMBER
214 DBAPS   ITCONTAH_REJEITADA_0512          CD_SETOR   NUMBER
215 DBAPS   ITCONTA_HOSPITALAR               CD_SETOR   NUMBER
216 DBAPS   ITCONTA_HOSPITALAR_0512          CD_SETOR   NUMBER
217 DBAPS   ITCONTA_MED                      CD_SETOR   NUMBER
218 DBAPS   ITCONTA_MED_0512                 CD_SETOR   NUMBER
219 DBAPS   ITCONTA_MED_REJEITADA            CD_SETOR   NUMBER
220 DBAPS   ITCONTA_MED_REJEITADA_0512       CD_SETOR   NUMBER
221 DBAMV   V_LOTE_ATENDIMENTO               CD_SETOR   NUMBER
```

Só que essas tabelas estão populadas com códigos que não existem mais, e eu quero fazer um update em todas elas de uma única vez para. Ex (Onde existir os códigos XPTO na coluna CD_SETOR em todas as tabelas encontradas, altere para XPT).

Objetivo: Não fazer update tabela por tabela, são mais de 500 tabelas com a mesma FK.

Comment: Olhar o link abaixo deve ajudar voce a resolver o problema http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_cascade_update.htm

Comment: Qual a opção de CASCADE da FK ? Uma solução pode ser montar um sql que gere um script de atualização , como seria uma execução única seria viável

Answer (score 1):

Melhorando a resposta do Robinho

```
DECLARE
  VN_ALTERADOS NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR R IN (select 'update '||owner||'.'||table_name|| ' set '||column_name||'= 406 where '||column_name||' in (20)' LINHA 
            from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS where column_name = 'CD_SETOR') 
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (R.LINHA);
    VN_ALTERADOS := VN_ALTERADOS + SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VN_ALTERADOS);
END;
```

'setando' o serveroutput on.

Comment: +1 por mostrar para o AP como se faz o `FOR ... LOOP EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer fazer um UPDATE você precisa usar "UPDATE" ao invés de "SELECT", você precisa buscar os valores antigos e atualiza-los junto ao WHERE, isso talvez resolva seu problema: **(FAÇA UM BACKUP DA SUA BASE DE DADOS ANTES DE REALIZAR ESSA OPERAÇÃO)**

```
UPDATE `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` SET `CD_SETOR`='XPT' WHERE `CD_SETOR`=XPTO;
```

Caso use mais de 1 base de dados no servidor, não se esqueça de escolher a base de dados antes da operação através do:

```
use nomedabasededados;
```

Answer (score 0):

Um DBA me ajudou e o script correto é:

```
select 'update '||owner||'.'||table_name|| ' set '||column_name||'= 406 where '||column_name||' in (20);'  from DBA_TAB_COLUMNS where column_name = 'CD_SETOR';
```